# Using variables in jquery in Django template filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jinja2

I want to be able to get data using **Jquery** then apply a **Django** template filter on it. I am using `jinja2` for the template.

I have a click event as to:

```
$('#get_name').click(function(event){
    var name = $(this).val();
    alert('{{ name|custom_filter}}'); - here is where it is producing the error.
});
```

I have tried appending it as `'{{ " + name + "|custom_filter}}'` but still produces an error.

Comment: Posting the error is always a helpful start.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Template rendering is done on the server side. Javascript is executed on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix client-side code and server-side code. You are attempting to apply a template filter to a javascript variable that do not yet exist and is just a piece of text to the template engine. Both scopes are completely different and not even executed on the same machine.

You have to write a javascript function `custom_filter` (that hopefully does the same thing as the template tag) and just call it:

```
$('#get_name').click(function(event){
    var name = $(this).val();
    alert(custom_filter(name));
});
```

Why would you use a template tag for that?